# Python Local development how to check syntax error

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am new to Python. I am working in a large project with multiple languages and one component is in python. That means I cannot run this python component in my Pycharm.

So I modified some python code. How do I know if I have any syntax errors?
In C++ I always compile it then I can see what errors I have so I can fix them.

Thanks!

Comment: There are a lot of online syntax checkers, for examples: https://extendsclass.com/python-tester.html

Comment: While you may not be able to _execute_ the code in PyCharm, it should be able to highlight any syntax errors and issues if you have installed linters such as flake8, pylint etc.